# Convert an Informix SQL query into ANSI-92 SQL?

Tags: informix

What is the ANSI-92 equivalent of the following old Informix SQL query?

```
select * 
from categories c,
  orders o, 
  outer (employees e, person p) 
where c.categoryid = o.categoryid
  and p.personid = e.id
  and o.employeeid = e.id
  and o.orderid = 7742
  and e.term_date is NULL
```

I cannot seem to figure out exactly what the "outer (table1, table2)" syntax means.

Comment: OK, ummm... apparently I had the answer in front of me the whole time. The only problem was it was timing out because I didn't have an ORDER BY clause. As soon as I added ORDER BY c.categoryid it ran fine. Is this normal? I would think adding an ORDER BY would take more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
select  *
from        categories c
Join        orders o
on          c.categoryid = o.categoryid
Left Join employees e
on          o.employeeid = e.id
Join        person p
on          e.id = p.personid
where       o.orderid = 7742
and         e.term_data is null
```

Answer (score 2):

[Mike Burdick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4283637/mike-burdick)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27584716/15168) is, I believe, essentially correct — but I'm not completely sure of that. I'd be a little more comfortable with the comparison if the query were written as:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Categories AS C
  JOIN Orders     AS O ON C.CategoryID = O.CategoryID
  LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT * FROM
          FROM Employees AS E
          JOIN Person    AS P ON E.ID = P.PersonID
       ) AS E ON O.EmployeeID = E.ID
 WHERE O.OrderID = 7742
   AND E.Term_Data IS NULL
```

The `OUTER (Employees e, Person p)` in the original query is an inner-join sub-query that is outer-joined to the main query, which I've made clearer in my version by using the sub-query, but I think Mike's version is OK too.  My concern is that Mike's version might more nearly equivalent to this (where the parentheses around `employees e` are optional in this scenario):

```
select * 
from categories c,
  orders o, 
  outer (employees e),
  person p
where c.categoryid = o.categoryid
  and p.personid = e.id
  and o.employeeid = e.id
  and o.orderid = 7742
  and e.term_date is NULL
```

I'd need to think hard before coming up with data sets that could distinguish between the two queries (either the original query in the question and the slight rewrite above, or between Mike's answer and mine).

One other nagging doubt is that Informix's old-style non-standard OUTER join notation has a quirk that the standard notation simply does not support. The problem can occur when filtering on data in the subordinate table (RHS of a left outer join).  The rows in the dominant table (in this case, tables — orders and categories) are preserved by Informix even when there was a match in the subordinate table that got filtered out.  I think that it works OK this time because the filter condition that I'm concerned about, which is `AND e.term_date IS NULL`, uses `IS NULL`.  You could run into the problem if the filter condition was `AND e.term_date > MDY(7,4,2032)` (*and there was a row in employees that did not match the filter condition*), but I think `IS NULL` is OK.  The Informix behaviour is hard to explain, and hard to justify beyond "that is the way it works and it was documented to work thus in 1987±2 years, and backwards compatibility deals with the rest".  It is *only* the Informix-only OUTER join notation that behaves weirdly.  The ANSI-standard LEFT OUTER JOIN notation works according to the standard.  But it does make conversion a challenge if this quirk affects your legacy code.

**TL;DR** Test the query results very carefully.

Comment: One thing to clarify is whether the Employees to Person relationship is required or optional, i.e. is Employees.ID nullable.  If it is nullable then you want to have a left outer join between Employees and Person.

Comment: Are you aware of any performance hit to using ANSI `JOIN`'s rather than Informix `JOIN`'s?  I just posted [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28485239/how-to-convert-sql-from-old-informix-style-to-ansi-style).