# How to convert SQL from old Informix-style to ANSI-style?

Tags: sql, informix

I have some queries written in Informix-style SQL.  Specifically, this query selects the items in a customer's order.  (I've simplified the table structure somewhat, though I kept the part that is problematic.)

```
SELECT ordi.line_no, ordi.item_code, ordi.desc, ordi.price,
    shpi.location, shpi.status, shpi.ship_code,
    box.box_no, box.tracking_no, shpc.ship_co, mfr.mfr_name,
    sum(shpi.ship_qty), sum(shpi.net_cost)
FROM order_items ordi, ship_items shpi, OUTER ship_boxes box,
    shipping_companies shpc, OUTER (inventory invt, brand, manufacturer mfr)
WHERE ordi.order_id = ?
    AND shpi.order_id = ordi.order_id AND shpi.line_no = ordi.line_no
    AND box.order_id = ordi.order_id AND box.box_no = shpi.box_no
    AND shp.shipper_code = shpi.shipper_code
    AND invt.item_code = ordi.item_code
        AND brand.brand_no = invt.brand_no
        AND mfr.mfr_code = brand.mfr_code
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
ORDER BY ordi.line_no ASC;
```

(The reason inventory is joined by `OUTER` is because a certain class of items is stored in a different inventory table.  The `OUTER` on ship_boxes is for items that were not packed yet.)

I'm rewrote it with standard, ANSI-style `JOIN`'s.  Here is what I got:

```
SELECT ordi.line_no, ordi.item_code, ordi.desc, ordi.price, shpi.location,
    shpi.status, shpi.ship_code, box.box_no, box.tracking_no, shpc.ship_co,
    mfr.mfr_name, sum(shpi.ship_qty), sum(shpi.net_cost)
FROM order_items ordi
    JOIN ship_items shpi ON shpi.order_id = ordi.order_id
        AND shpi.line_no = ordi.line_no
    LEFT JOIN ship_boxes box ON box.order_id = ordi.order_id
        AND box.box_no = shpi.box_no
    JOIN shipping_companies shpc ON shpc.shipper_code = shpi.shipper_code
    LEFT JOIN (inventory invt
        JOIN brand ON brand.brand_no = invt.brand_no
        JOIN manufacturer mfr ON mfr.mfr_code = brand.mfr_code
        ) ON invt.item_code = ordi.item_code
WHERE ordi.order_id = ?
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
ORDER BY ordi.line_no ASC;
```

The result set is exactly the same, but the performance hit is nearly 2 orders of magnitude.  For an order with 50 items, the first query takes about 50 milliseconds, while the second takes about 5 seconds.  Running an Explain gives a cost of 25 to the first query, and a cost of 14403 to the second.  I was able to pin down the difference to the complex join of inventory: the Informix-style query performed it as 3 `INDEX PATH` / `NESTED LOOP JOIN`'s, each having cost of 1; the ANSI `JOIN`'s were performed as a `SEQUENTIAL SCAN`, with cost of 383 at that point, adding up to over 14K points.

It seems that the ANSI `JOIN`'s work on the entire inventory / brand / manufacturer table, which is then `LEFT JOIN`'ed to the order items.  The Informix `OUTER (...)` is able to work on the small selection of that table that I asked for (the items in the order).

What am I doing wrong?  Is there a way to write the query ANSI-style that won't give me that performance hit?  If I must, I'll go back to the Informix-style `JOIN`'s, but I am really hoping there is another way.

Thank you.

***EDIT:*** Here are the results from `SET EXPLAIN`:

1. Original query: Estimated Cost: 18
2. My rewrite (explicit `JOIN`'s): Estimated Cost: 15629
3. @HartCO's suggestion (unbundle inventory section):  Estimated Cost: 18 (but will the data be the same?  Why isn't that like `OUTER inventory, brand, manufacturer`?)

Comment: I'm not aware of a performance hit of that magnitude.  Have you studied the query plan from `SET EXPLAIN ON`?  Some outline schema might be relevant, too: the numbers of columns, rows, and row size at least.  And the query plan might show where you need to make improvements.

Comment: What database are you running the updated queries on?

Comment: If we want to be super technical (and who doesn't on Stack Overflow?) comma joins *are* ANSI joins.  They just stopped being ANSI SQL after ANSI-89.  Beginning with ANSI-92, the `JOIN ... ON` syntax was presented as preferable.  We don't like to talk about the *other* methods included in ANSI-92, however....

Comment: Both on the same database. IBM Informix 1.7, according to `DBInfo`.  I'm working on the `EXPLAIN` plan.  It was hard to get a hold of, but I just spoke to on of the local DBAs who showed me how.  (I'm connecting to the DB across a network, and `sqexplain.out` is created on the local database box, not my client machine.)  But the numbers I gave (25 and 14K) came from an Explain plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unbundle your `Inventory` join section and change those to `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT ordi.line_no     , ordi.item_code     , ordi.DESC        , ordi.price
     , shpi.location    , shpi.STATUS        , shpi.ship_code   , box.box_no
     , box.tracking_no  , shpc.ship_co       , mfr.mfr_name     
     , sum(shpi.ship_qty)
     , sum(shpi.net_cost)
FROM order_items ordi
    JOIN ship_items shpi ON  shpi.order_id = ordi.order_id   
        AND shpi.line_no = ordi.line_no
    LEFT JOIN ship_boxes box ON box.order_id = ordi.order_id
        AND box.box_no = shpi.box_no
    LEFT JOIN shipping_companies shpc ON shpc.shipper_code = box.shipper_code
    LEFT JOIN inventory invt ON invt.item_code = ordi.item_code
    LEFT JOIN brand ON brand.brand_no = invt.brand_no
    LEFT JOIN manufacturer mfr ON mfr.mfr_code = brand.mfr_code    
WHERE ordi.order_id = ?
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
ORDER BY ordi.line_no ASC;
```

Note:  I only have a SQL Server instance to test on, but I see big difference in the execution plan, my query shows a `Nested Loops (Left Outer Join)` which gets executed once, while yours shows `Nested Loops (Inner Join)` that gets executed 3 times.  Certainly seems like the culprit.

Your `LEFT JOIN ship_boxes` was effectively an `INNER JOIN` because you used  `JOIN shipping_companies` to join to that table.  If the results from the above query aren't as desired you should change both from `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN`.

Comment: `JOIN shipping_companies shpc ON shpc.shipper_code = box.shipper_code` needs to be a `LEFT JOIN shipping_companies shpc ON shpc.shipper_code = box.shipper_code`.  The table for `box` is a left joined table.

Comment: @BaconBits Good point, I was focued on the `inventory` join since that was deemed to be the problematic one, I've updated accordingly even though OP indicated results were correct in the query with poor performance.

Comment: I think it was just that it was easier to see what was going on in your query.  I didn't notice in the original that the error was there!  I guess that speaks towards maintainability.

Comment: Good point.  Checking the original code, `shipping_companies` was indeed `JOIN`ed to `ship_items` (the field is duplicated, and is actually in the `order_items` and `orders` tables as well).  I updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: That would seem to be equivalent to the Informix `OUTER inventory, OUTER brand, OUTER manufacturer` rather than to what I have above: `OUTER (inventory invt, brand, manufacturer mfr)`.  Unless I'm misunderstanding how Informix treats its `OUTER(...)` syntax.

Comment: @Menachem It's equivalent in function to your original query, it's just more performant than your attempt because of how it handles those bundled/grouped joins.  I can't speak to why the optimizer doesn't recognize them as equivalent.

Comment: @HartCO Thanks.  That's what I was waiting to hear.  I just hope I don't have any data that would be eliminated by `INNER JOIN`'ing `inventory` to `brand` to `manufacturer` that would not be eliminated by `LEFT JOIN`ing them all to `order_items`.  BTW, a separate `OUTER` on table of the Inventory section gave me an error ("two-sided outer join"), and omitting the parentheses around them did a full scan of brand and mfr, and failed to filter the non-matches.

Comment: I just wanted to give an update: The fix here was just rolled out to Production code, and is working perfectly. Thanks, y'all.

Comment: @Menachem Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

My decomposition of the original query is close but with some significant differences.

First, `shipping_company` is definitely an inner join. This makes sense as this seems to be a readout of the items that have at least been sent to the shipper. The shipper may not have yet loaded everything into boxes, so from `ship_boxes` on down is an outer join.

One outer join that makes no sense is `inventory`. Could items that were not in inventory have been sent to the shipper? Maybe I'm reading this relationship wrong, but in the meantime, I changed it to an inner -- also the `brand` and `manufacturer` which followed it in the join chain. That left `ship_boxes` as the sole surviving outer join.

Another thing that was curious was the double relationship of `ship_boxes` to both `ship_items` and `order_items`. This locks down an entire box to one order. If the entire order was a pack of playing cards, there's going to be a lot of wasted space in that box. On the assumption that one box could quite easily contain more than one order, I eliminated that connection. Now, I realize a "ship_box" does not necessarily have to be an entire shipping container. It could be a cardboard box sized just to fit the order or part of order. That makes no difference. The `order_id` connected to the box can be had from `ship_items`. Having a duplicate `order_id` field in `ship_boxes` is an unneeded redundancy that, as far as I could tell, makes no difference in the execution plan.

My final query, using SQL Server:

```
select  ordi.line_no, ordi.item_code, ordi.item_desc, ordi.price,
        shpi.location, shpi.status, shpi.ship_code,
        box.box_no, box.tracking_no, shpc.ship_co, mfr.mfr_name,
        sum(shpi.ship_qty), sum(shpi.net_cost)
from    order_items ordi
join    ship_items shpi
    on  shpi.order_id = ordi.order_id
    and shpi.line_no = ordi.line_no
left join ship_boxes box
    on  box.box_no = shpi.box_no --AND box.order_id = ordi.order_id
join    shipping_companies shpc
    on  shpc.shipper_code = shpi.shipper_code
join    inventory invt
    on  invt.item_code = ordi.item_code
join    brand
    on  brand.brand_no = invt.brand_no
join    manufacturer mfr
    on  mfr.mfr_code = brand.mfr_code
where ordi.order_id = 1
group by ordi.line_no, ordi.item_code, ordi.item_desc, ordi.price,
        shpi.location, shpi.status, shpi.ship_code,
        box.box_no, box.tracking_no, shpc.ship_co, mfr.mfr_name
order by ordi.line_no;
```

I created the tables and loaded them with some test data. The result set is correct and the execution plan looks simple and right what I would expect it to be.

Now, if my assumption about inventory is wrong, changing that chain back to outer joins really doesn't change the execution plan.

Comment: Several points: 1) `shipping_company` is indeed `INNER JOIN`'ed to `ship_items`, as corrected. 2) Your question about about `inventory` - curious indeed - is addressed in my original post (between the two code snippets): A certain class of items is stored in a separate table, with a different sequence of item code. Thus the required `OUTER`/`LEFT JOIN`.  3) We most definitely need a separate `ship_boxes` entry for each order. Even if you're only buying a pack of cards, we can't very well send your neighbor's tuna can in the same box, can we?

Comment: Yes, well there was no indication if "shipping box" was a large container loaded on a ship or just a mailer. Having different inventories is puzzling but I'm sure there is a reason. The only change to the query then is change the join chain starting at inventory to left joins. Have you managed to get the performance to where it should be?